# MacBook Pro early 2011 WiFi says it's on but it's not (new fresh install 10.8.5 (12f45)

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook

WiFi log:

```
Dec 17 00:30:01 cmb-macbook-pro newsyslog[461]: logfile turned over
Tue Dec 17 01:18:33.235 <airportd[489]> _doAutoJoin: Already associated to "linksys_media". Bailing on auto-join.
Tue Dec 17 01:18:33.267 <airportd[489]> _doAutoJoin: Already associated to "linksys_media". Bailing on auto-join.
Tue Dec 17 02:36:41.283 <configd[18]> _apAppleWoWCapable: Failed to retrieve AP IE list (Operation not supported)
Tue Dec 17 21:51:37.720 <airportd[2001]> _handleNewMessage: Received XPC message, event = SC_CHANGED_EVENT, pid = 18
Tue Dec 17 21:51:38.390 <airportd[2001]> startAutoJoinForInterface: autojoin failed, interface OFF
Tue Dec 17 21:52:07.288 <airportd[2001]> ___createTerminateTimer_block_invoke_0: …exiting
```

Constant "WIFI: looking for Networks" on the menu drop down. There are plenty of networks nearby (including mine) and the computer doesn't see any. I've got it plugged in to the ethernet to send this. Inn the network control panel it says that wifi is off. I try to click the button to enable it, but nothing happens.

Upon restart, WiFi is on at login. Then, sometime later nothing.